# Tools to check the firewall Configurations as per PCI standards

Tags: firewalls, pci-dss, configuration

How do you audit the Firewall rules and configuration policies as per [PCI standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).
What are the tools used for it.

Answer (score 1):

Firewall auditing requires knowledge and interpretation, so there are no tools that will go 'ding!' and tell you you're compliant.  However, various tools can be used to make the review and audit process easier.  Two that I've used are:

- [Tufin SecureTrack](http://www.tufin.com/products-solutions/products/firewall-management-securetrack/)
- [Nipper Studio](https://www.titania.com/nipperstudio)

And many tools will do, e.g. see [Firewall rule base documentation and migration tools](http://itexperience.co.nz/2009/10/09/firewall-rule-base-documentation-and-migration-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

You can you use CIS benchmarks to evaluate your Firewall rules and configurations. 
It is very comprehensive and easy to understand and FREE. 
[CIS benchmarks](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/browse/index.cfm?category=tools)